# How to add class for certain elements from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of banned users, and it looks like this:

[banned list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH9T4.jpg)

code:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="inner">

    <h3>{L_UNBAN_TITLE}</h3>
    <p>{L_UNBAN_EXPLAIN}</p>

    <!-- IF S_BANNED_OPTIONS -->
        <fieldset>
        <!-- EVENT mcp_ban_unban_before -->
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="unban">{L_BAN_CELL}{L_COLON}</label></dt>
            <dd><select name="unban[]" id="unban" multiple="multiple" size="5" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex != -1) {display_details(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);}">{BANNED_OPTIONS}</select></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>{L_BAN_LENGTH}{L_COLON}</dt>
            <dd><strong id="unbanlength"></strong></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>{L_BAN_REASON}{L_COLON}</dt>
            <dd><strong id="unbanreason"></strong></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>{L_BAN_GIVE_REASON}{L_COLON}</dt>
            <dd><strong id="unbangivereason"></strong></dd>
        </dl>
        <!-- EVENT mcp_ban_unban_after -->
        </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
```

So I need to add class with jQuery only to users from the list.

How can be this done ? It needs to check the banned list, and then add class to this users from the list ?

The problem is that I dont know who will be banned, and I cant set the var

like this: var $banned = 'bot';

because i dont know is banned or not... so the function needs to check the list and then add class to user from list.

Thank you

Comment: Show the code not an image

Comment: I edited the question...

Comment: first you need to manage a list of banned users in JS, not only as html-markup! Then, you probably want to apply add this class on all clients, on only for the mod who banned the user, right? Then yon need to tell us how something about how you store and propagate this status.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var banned=document.getElementById('ofbot')
 if ( banned ) {
        $('#ofbot').addClass('banned').removeClass('notBanned');

    } else {
        $('#ofbot').removeClass('notBanned').addClass('banned');
    }
});
```

Comment: this could work only if I know who is banned... it would be great when var could be all users from the list

Comment: i can think only one whay to know ho is banned that is to store all users in date base and then up date that user that got banned and then use jquery to show that he is banned